# leftBarButtonItem in UINavigationItem

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I've looked through several threads and come to a solution that I thought would work.

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbutton.psd"]
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self
                                                              action:@selector(barButtonBackPressed:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

This gives me nothing.

When I add this it gives me a regular blue bordered button (which isn't what I want) with the text "Back":

```
backButton.title = @"Back";
```

I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because you're using a PSD image file. That's not a supported format according to [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).